# Can we do day level forecast clubbing all the data of single day?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I've day level sales data. If I select let say all monday sales from this data. Can I make a time series of all Monday sales which can accurately predict the future.
If I can, how reliable is that forecast?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain what your "clubbing" operation is?  This is not a standard English statistical term.

Answer (score 0):

[Simple method of forecasting number of guests given current and historical data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313810/simple-method-of-forecasting-number-of-guests-given-current-and-historical-data/313852#313852) would be a good place to start. Daily data often contains deterministic and arima structure. I would not take each day by itself and build separate models as there is often an auto-dependency on previous days i.e. ARIMA structure. .