# Data Pre Processing Regression Analysis

Tags: regression, time-series, data-preprocessing, marketing

I am preparing a regression analysis of sales data and advertisement data. The sales data is from Monday to Sunday, but Sundays have a value of 0 because the store is closed. The advertisement data from Monday to Sunday has values way greater than 0 on Sunday. It is for a Marketing Mix Modeling project.

How can I deal with that? Is that called noisy data or something else? Do I just remove the Sunday altogether?

Thank you in advance for any hints how to research that further.

Comment: Use a dummy variable with value 1 for sunday and 0 for everything else.

Comment: How is a dummy variable going to help in that case? I don't understand.

Comment: Ok. I found the answer myself. Basically it is a time series analysis and I just need to deseasonalize it.

Comment: No, a dummy variable will tell the model to treat sundays differently than the other days.

Answer (score 0):

Use 6 dummies to deal with day-of-the-week and delete any of these indicators if they are not significant. Introduce Holiday indicators allowing for lead , contemporaneous and lag effects. Look at [Simple method of forecasting number of guests given current and historical data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313810/simple-method-of-forecasting-number-of-guests-given-current-and-historical-data/313852#313852) for more model development strategies.