# Determine order of (p,d,q) & (P,D,Q,s) in SARIMAX Python

Tags: time-series, python, arima

I am trying to build SARIMAX model, trying to determine the (p,d,q) & (P,D,Q,s) values from ACF, PACF plots. My series is stationary without any differencing being required (based on ADF test). While I understand from PACF plot that p=2 & q=2 (though ACF is decaying exponentially, I believe it could be due to cumulative effect of lags on each other) should be good enough, I am slightly confused as to how I can arrive at the P,Q values for the seasonal part. My data is daily observations collected for about 4 years. From the below seasonal part of the decomposition, I could see that pattern repeats itself for every 7 days. Here is the ACF, PACF plots for the undifferenced original data.

I am also confused on the 's' value in (P,D,Q,s) whether to consider as 365 (as data is daily observations) or 7 ( as the pattern repeats itself every week).

Appreciate your guidance in helping me identify the P,Q values for the seasonal part of the series.

[image: ACF PACF Plot]
[image: ACF-PACF-After Differencing by 7 days]
[image: Seasonal Component]

Comment: Post your data in a csv file and I will try and help. You should know that if you have daily deterministic effects (probably !) , the acf and pacf have to be computed taking into these effects and possible holiday effects . See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313810/simple-method-of-forecasting-number-of-guests-given-current-and-historical-data/313852#313852

Comment: not sure how you can do this in Python ...Perhaps others can suggest how hybrid models can be identified and estimated .

Comment: Unfortunately due to organization restrictions I can't post the actual data

Comment: code the data … that will mask it ….